# Vector spaces: Name for restricting scalar multiplication to a subfield

Tags: linear-algebra, terminology

Say we have a complex vector space $V$? Do we have a name for the real vector space obtained by restricting the scalar product to $\mathbb{R}$? (I like to denote it as $\mathbb{V}_\mathbb{R}$, but I don't know if it has a standard name.)

More generally, say we have a field extension $\mathbb{L}\leq\mathbb{K}$. Consider the forgetful functor from the category of $\mathbb{K}$-vector spaces to the category of $\mathbb{L}$-vector spaces. Does this functor have a name? Do we have a name for the $\mathbb{L}$-vector space obtained from a $\mathbb{K}$-vector space?

Answer (score 1):

This functor is called "[restriction of scalars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weil_restriction#:%7E:text=In%20mathematics%2C%20restriction%20of%20scalars,kX%2C%20defined%20over%20k.)." I general if we have a ring homomorphism $f:R\to S$ then this induces a functor $S\mathrm{-mod}\to R\mathrm{-mod}$ which sends an $S$-module $M$ to the $R$-module with the same underlying abelian group and the multiplication given by $r\cdot m:=f(r)m.$

There's also the "extension of scalars" functor going in the other direction which is just given by $-\otimes_R S$ where we use $f$ to consider $S$ as an $R$-module.